# Identifying the frequency of items in the list

Tags: r, reshape

I have a dataframe like below.

```
11,15,12,25
11,12
15,25
134,45,56
46
45,56
15,12
66,45,56,24,14,11,25,12,134
```

I want to identify the frequency of pairs/triplets or higher that occurs in the data. Say for example, in above data the occurrence of pairs looks like below

```
item     No of occurrence
11,12      3
11,25      2
15,12      2
15,25      2
.
.
45,56      3
134,45,56  2    ....and so on
```

I am trying to write a R code for the above and I am finding difficulty to approach this.

Comment: Please do not tag your Q with all tags for which you'd like an answer with.

Comment: It's possible to have the head() of the dataframe and the str()

Comment: That is not a valid data frame structure.

Comment: If your data frame `dat` is a list you could do something like `new <- lapply(lapply(dat, function(x) data.frame(table(x))),function(y) y[y$Freq>=2,])`;`new[sapply(new,function(z) nrow(z)>=1)]`

Comment: Hi, the data I provided here is just a direct column where I want to apply the function. the head and str of the data frame is found in the image here  [link] (http://imgur.com/IpM9Rtw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a 1 column data.frame with commas separating the variables, the following should produce your desired result:

```
# split column into a list
myList <- strsplit(df$V1, split=",")
# get all pairwise combinations
myCombos <- t(combn(unique(unlist(myList)), 2))

# count the instances where the pair is present
myCounts <- sapply(1:nrow(myCombos), FUN=function(i) {
                   sum(sapply(myList, function(j) {
                              sum(!is.na(match(c(myCombos[i,]), j)))})==2)})

# construct final matrix
allDone <- cbind(matrix(as.integer(myCombos), nrow(myCombos)), myCounts)
```

This returns a matrix where the first two columns are the items in comparison and the third column of the count that these items are in the row of the data.frame.

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text="11,15,12,25
11,12
15,25
134,45,56
46
45,56
15,12
66,45,56,24,14,11,25,12,134", as.is=TRUE)
```

Comment: @Imo This did the magic. Thank you so much. And one more thing, is it possible to check all the combination rather than only pairs. Say for example making all possible combinations and counting the frequency for the particular combination in the data frame

Comment: This is possible, though a bit more tedious to code up: you have to add an additional loop where myCombos changes and you adjust the second argument of `combn(, k)`. In this new loop, k would be adjusted from 2 to some larger integer.